# Installation on Macbook Pro

Tags: system-installation

After asking to install ubuntu to my macbook pro 2011, couldnt get size 0xB00000000000000e messages appear, as well as MODSIGN couldnt get uefi db list..  what shoud i do ?

Comment: try Rebooting your mac

Comment: Try legacy boot

Answer (score 0):

I had issues loading ubuntu on my 2010 macbook pro. But I was able to boot ubuntu budgie 19.10 without any issues and it works like a charm. 
I used rufus to create the bootable drive.